# How to make field in document unique?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data mongo. There is a field in `document` apart from `primary key` which needs to be unique but as per my requirement I can't use `@Indexed(unique=true)`. Is there any annotation like `@Column(unique=true)` in spring data mongo to make the field as a unique?

Comment: yes there is `@Column(unique=true)`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use `@Indexed(unique=true)`?

Comment: @Synch Actually I am also embedding that document to another document, in that case, it's restricting me to embed the same document.

Comment: @pvpkiran I tried @Column(unique=true) in spring data mongo but it's not working.Is the similar type of annotation present in spring data mongo?

Comment: in the question you said spring data jpa. now you are saying mongo. Be clear about what you want to ask. Edit your question to be specific so that it can help others. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a sparse index in this case.

Try `@Indexed(unique=true, sparse=true)`. Do read the documentation for this type of index [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#unique-indexes)

Comment: It's allowing the duplicate entries.

Comment: Not working so not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Following method can also be used to define `indexes` programmatically. The advantage of this method is that it provides programmatic control for defining indexes.

```
this.mongoTemplate.indexOps(<Document>.class).ensureIndex(new Index("<fieldName>", Direction.ASC).unique());
```